# Apache occasionally hangs, won't stop or restart

Tags: virtualbox, apache2, nfs

Once a week or so, apache just becomes completely unresponsive. If I try `service apache2 restart`, it says it's stopping apache, but then sits there. Sometimes killing all the processes works, but sometimes even that doesn't allow me to successfully restart. A restart of the whole server solves the problem, but sometimes even when I think apache is dead, the shutdown process hangs at `* Stopping web server apache2`, forcing me to reach for the (virtual) reset button.

FWIW, if I killall apache processes and try to start, it does the same thing. It just says it's starting and never starts.

Apache error log shows nothing except SIGTERM caught.

Since stopping the processes doesn't seem to consistently help, could it be something file related? A locked file? A weird configuration? PHP?

The system is 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 running in a VirtualBox instance. I used nfs to share files with my desktop, and that's where my virtualhosts are. Other than that, pretty vanilla apache and php on ubuntu.

I have Googled like a man obsessed to no avail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When apache hangs again, try to use `strace` to attach to the process using PID and see the syscalls made and signals received by the process. This will help to get closer to the root cause.
   Example: `strace -tT -pPID`, Output to a file `strace -tT -pPID -o /path/to/tmux_output`
2. Make sure you upgrade VirtualBox to 4.2.16 and install Guest Additions for the guest.
3. Try to move your files to local file system instead of serving from NFS.

Comment: 1. I didn't see any output from `strace`.
2. Was already there
3. This would be pretty inconvenient, I edit these files locally and they appear on my dev ubuntu instance right away. Would you recommend a better way to share them?

Comment: How about using `sshfs` to mount directory via ssh and edit files as if they are local files?

Comment: I did some more investigating and it is almost certainly nfs related. If I `umount -lf` then the `mount` call hangs when I try to remount it. What a hassle. I will give sshfs a try, thanks!

Comment: A day later and so far, so good .. if it gives me any of the same problems I'll be back ;)

Comment: Good to hear;-) Could be related to the NFS lock (check mount option lock/unlock if you are interested).